# How can I check if the current code is inside a certain environment?

Tags: environments, conditionals

I would like to define a command which checks if it is executed inside a certain environment. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myenv}[0]{at start}{ at end}

\newcommand{\inner}[0]{%
  % if iside a myenv
  (inner)
  % else
  \begin{myenv}
  (inner)%
  \end{myenv}
  % end
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
  \inner
\end{myenv}

\inner

\end{document}
```

See the definition of `\inner`. Is an if-condition of this form possible?

Comment: Related Question: [Detecting if inside a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458849/4301)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

LaTeX keeps the current environment in the macro `\@currenvir`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\inner}{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\@myenvname
    (inner)
  \else
    \begin{myenv}(inner)\end{myenv}
  \fi}
\newcommand*\@myenvname{myenv}
\makeatother
```

Another approach would be to define a global conditional that's set to true by `myenv` start code and to false by `myenv` end code. It depends mostly on what you are expecting from the `myenv` environment: can it appear nested inside itself?

Comment: @Nickoley: Note that this doesn't work any longer when `\inner` is used inside another environment inside the `myenv` environment, e.g. \begin{myenv}\begin{center}\inner\end{center}\end{myenv}`. Then `\@currenvir` will be `center` when `\inner` is expanded.

Comment: This does not seem to work on my end. It produces the "else" output both inside and outside a `myenv` environment. However, both `\@currenvir` and `\@myenvname` display the correct (and the same) output when placed inside the environment.

Comment: @DannyHansen Right: in some update during the last eight years, the LaTeX kernel changed `\@currenvir` to not be `\long` as it used to be. Fixed by adding a `*`.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `pdftex`, `etex` or `xetex` (I mean engine), you can define a fully expandable test:

```
\makeatletter \def\IfEnvir #1%
% implicit #2 "what if true"
% implicit #3 "what if false"
{%
  \ifnum \strcmp{\@currenvir}{#1}=0
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\makeatother
```

Such a conditional is defined in the `gmutils` package: `\@ifenvir`, but there it's `\protected` for some reason.

Comment: If you prefer the \if… … \else … \fi form, just replace \expandafter\@first/secondoftwo with your stuff, but i'd suggest the arguments-form because it's robust to unbalanced \if's.

Comment: Please indent your code with four spaces (or use the '101010' button to do this) so that it is properly highlighted. Please don't use HTML for code formatting. Thanks.

Comment: the command is `\strcmp` in XeTeX and `\pdfstrcmp` in pdfTeX. One can load `pdftexcmds` and use `\pdf@strcmp` in all engines (including LuaTeX).