# using \marginnote inside a math environment in tufte-book

Tags: math-mode, page-breaking, margins, amsmath, tufte

I've recently started using `tufte-book` for typesetting solutions to math problems. I like it very much that you're encouraged to use the margin, which is very nice for giving hints, pointers and references concerning the steps of finding a solution.

Unfortunately, the `sidenote` and `marginnote` commands don't work in math environments *(not in outer par mode)*. Most of the time, I'm able to work around it by putting the commands after the environment, using the optional offset with a decimal value via `\marginnote[-length]{content}`. But this breaks when a math environment is pushed to the end of a page: the notes are then pushed to the next page, no longer appearing on the same page. This also happens if you first put the commands and then the environment.

So, is there any way to enable `sidenote` and `marginnote` in math environments?
(I thought of using the `samepage` environment, but this adds a lot of ugly whitespace, as the whole math environment is pushed to the next page without necessity)

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\filler}[1][10]%
{   \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
    {   test 
    }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{align*}
    &\int\int\int t\ dt^3\\
    =&\int\int \frac{t^2}{2}\ dt^2\\
    =&\int  \frac{t^3}{6}\ dt\\
    =&\frac{t^4}{24}
\end{align*}\marginnote[-3.7cm]{first note}\marginnote[-1.7cm]{second note}

\lipsum[2]
\filler[50]

\begin{align*}
    &\int\int\int t\ dt^3\\
    =&\int\int \frac{t^2}{2}\ dt^2\\
    =&\int  \frac{t^3}{6}\ dt\\
    =&\frac{t^4}{24}
\end{align*}\marginnote[-3.7cm]{first note}\marginnote[-1.7cm]{second note}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the second `align*` is still on the first page, but the `marginnote`s are pushed to the second page.

Comment: I see three notes: the first "first note", the first "second note" and the second "second note". Where did the second "first note" end up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The AMS environments conveniently give you a hook to place text at a known position relative to the margin so I'd do

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\filler}[1][10]%
{   \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
    {   test 
    }
}

\def\mathnote#1{%
  \tag*{\rlap{\hspace\marginparsep\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{%
  \footnotesize#1}}}}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{align*}
    &\int\int\int t\ dt^3\\
    =&\int\int \frac{t^2}{2}\ dt^2\\
    =&\int  \frac{t^3}{6}\ dt\\
    =&\frac{t^4}{24}
\end{align*}\marginnote[-3.7cm]{first note}\marginnote[-1.7cm]{second note}

\lipsum[2]
\filler[50]

\begin{align*}
    &\int\int\int t\ dt^3\mathnote{first note}\\
    =&\int\int \frac{t^2}{2}\ dt^2\\
    =&\int  \frac{t^3}{6}\ dt\\
    =&\frac{t^4}{24}\mathnote{second note}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. Your code was missing a closing `}` in the mathnote definition, so I took the liberty to add it.

Comment: After reading **Aleander Perlis'** [A complement to \smash, \llap, and \rlap](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/), I not only use your solution, but finally do _understand_ it. Thanks again.

Comment: +1! But just to be sure: This solution only works for the `align` environment and not for the `equation` environment? At least it failed in what I tested.

Comment: @flobo `equation*` works if you fix the definition by adding `\kern1sp` before the `\rlap`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Coincidentally, I was searching the answer to flobo's very question, only 24h after they asked.  In any case, it seems that adding the `\kern` does not break `\mathnote` in `align` environments. If that does make sense, maybe it'd be better to have it defined with the `\kern` in your answer?  Would you mind explaining what's happening with it?  Cheers!

Comment: @Michaël unlike align, equation uses the primitive tex (`$$`) equation number positioning, that has special rules for zero width labels (a trigger to move it after the equation) 1sp is an impossibly small length to measure, bit being non zero it forces equation to take the "normal" code path.

Comment: Is there a solution to invoke the correct command based on which environment it is in, using, e.g. LaTeX's `\@currenvir`? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18655/1362