# How to access name of environment in its own definition

Tags: environments

How can I get access to the name of an environment from within its own definition?

Consider, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{test}{This is som text from environment \printname :}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{test}
  text
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

I would like `\printname` to give the name of the environment, such that I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: LaTeX stores this in `\@currenvir`. That is, replace `\printname` with `\@currenvir` (with the accompanying `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` pair). However, this may be a duplicate of [Command behavior depending on current environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39738/5764) or [How can I check if the current code is inside a certain environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18652/5764)

Comment: Thank you.. Yes I see now that the topic has been covered before in the links you mention.. Sorry, I must have used the wrong search phrase on google, since I could not find them myself :)