# How to test whether I'm currently in a footnote or not

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, urls

Is there a way to test whether the current point is inside or outside a footnote or not?

The use case I have in mind is to provide two versions of a document, a "screen" one and a "printed" one and I'd like in the printed one automatically change the `\href{<URL>}{<text>}` into `<text>\footnote{\url{<URL>}}`, except in footnotes where this wouldn't make sense and `\href{<URL>}{<text>}` could be changed into  `<text> (\url{<URL>})`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below an possible answer adapted to your usecase. For this solution I redefined `\footnote` and `\href` and used to `if`-statements. To really check if one is in a certain environment see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-code-is-inside-a-certain-environment).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newif\ifprinted
\printedtrue % for printet version
% \printedfalse % for screen version

\newif\iffoot
\footfalse

\ifprinted
    \let\origfootnote\footnote
    \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\foottrue\origfootnote{#1}\footfalse}
    \renewcommand{\href}[2]{
        \iffoot
            #2 \url{#1}
        \else
            #2\footnote{#1}
        \fi
    }
\fi

\begin{document}
    One of the best \TeX-communities can be found on \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\TeX.SE}.
    There is a high probabilty that your \TeX-question is answered in a Q\&A-site\footnote{See for example \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\TeX.SE}.}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Though it doesn't strictly answer the original question, I marked your answer as accepted because it answers my use case. Nevertheless, I read (I don't remember where) that redefining macros with `\let` as in `\let\origfootnote\footnote` is not the recommended way anymore and that patching commands with e.g. `etoolbox` patching tools is preferable (okay, that requires e-TeX): am I wrong?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: This might be true and there is almost surely a more elegant solution. Yet, I am not familiar with the `etoolbox` package at all. Hence, I can only provide the following alternative to avoid the `\let` construction: Define `\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{\foottrue\footnote{#1}\footfalse}` in the `ifprinted` statement, add an `\else` with `\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{\footnote{#1}}`, and replace every `\footnote` with `\myfootnote` in the body of the text.

Comment: @crixstox Okay, I retrieve where I read redefining macros with `\let` is not recommended: in the documentation of the `xpatch` package, section 5 page 6 (though no explanation is given). In fact, it concerns only redefinition of macros that have an optional argument, hence your redefinition of `\footnote` with `\let\origfootnote\footnote` is perfectly advisable: sorry to have been suspicious ;)

Comment: > In fact, it concerns only redefinition of macros that have an optional argument, hence your redefinition of `\footnote` with `\let\origfootnote\footnote` is perfectly advisable.

Actually, `\footnote` _does_ have an optional argument. "The optional argument _number_ allows you to specify the number of the footnote." See [§11.1 `\footnote`](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html#g_t_005cfootnote) of the LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual (October 2018).