# footnote boolean: how to check whether currently in a footnote

Tags: macros, footnotes

Is there a way to check whether I'm currently in a footnote?

(This question has already been [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147350/how-to-test-if-im-currently-in-a-footnote-or-not) on tex.stackexchange.com, but the accepted answer only provides a solution to the user's specific issue but does not answer the question I am now posing.)

I'd like to be able to define a command, which I'll call `\mycommand`, which behaves one way in footnotes and another way when it appears outside of a footnote. Both cases may occur in the same document. It seems like I could define `\mycommand` using an `\ifthenelse` statement, but only if I know a command which will answer the question "am I currently in a footnote."

In other words, what should write for `X` in the following barebones example?

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{X}{...}{...}}
...
This is a paragraph \mycommand{...}.\footnote{This is a footnote.
Things should look different here \mycommand{...}.}
```

Or is there a better approach to take?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be easily adapted to your case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\iffoot
\footfalse

\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\foottrue\origfootnote{#1}\footfalse}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \iffoot%
    (#1 is inside a footnote)%  here put what the command has to do when inside
  \else%
    (#1 is outside a footnote)%  here put what the command has to do when outside
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}
This is a paragraph \mycommand{hello}.\footnote{This is a footnote.
Things should look different here \mycommand{hello}.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer a solution with `\ifthenelse` and `\boolean` here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{X}
\setboolean{X}{false}

\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\setboolean{X}{true}\origfootnote{#1}\setboolean{X}{false}}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{X}}%
  {(#1 is inside a footnote)}%  here put what the command has to do when inside
  {(#1 is outside a footnote)}%  here put what the command has to do when outside
  }

\begin{document}
This is a paragraph \mycommand{hello}.\footnote{This is a footnote.
Things should look different here \mycommand{hello}.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AlexRoberts You're welcome. Happy to help :-)