# Problem patching by appending to \footnote command. "Missing \endcsname inserted"

Tags: footnotes, etoolbox, xpatch

I want to test whether a macro is (a) outside or (b) inside a `\footnote` command, similar to what's asked in (i) [How to test if I'm currently in a footnote or not](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147350/how-to-test-if-im-currently-in-a-footnote-or-not), (ii) [Detect whether I'm in a `\footnote`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171681/detect-whether-im-in-a-footnote), (iii) [footnote boolean: how to check whether currently in a footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155878/footnote-boolean-how-to-check-whether-currently-in-a-footnote), and (iv) [same command with output X in main body and Y in footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150205/same-command-with-output-x-in-main-body-and-y-in-footnote).

The general technique is (1) define a boolean, defaulted to false; (2) redefine `\footnote` so that it sets the boolean to true upon entry and resets it to false when exiting. This requires a prepending and an appending to the original `\footnote` command.

Where my question differs from the answers given for (i)–(iii) above is that they all do the redefinition with a `\let`. However, though it's often forgotten, the `\footnote` command takes an optional argument (for the number of the footnote). (E.g., see ["`\footnote`"](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html#g_t_005cfootnote) of [LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual (October 2018)](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html).) This fact should make using `\let` inappropriate. (E.g., "Remember that one must *never* use the old trick `\let\ORIxyz\xzy`… if `\xyz` has been defined with an optional argument." [`xpatch` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xpatch/xpatch.pdf))

(The answer in (iv) redefines `\footnotetext` rather than `\footnote`, which I don't understand.)

Thus, I want to redefine `\footnote` using the commands `\xpretocmd` and `\xapptocmd` from the `xpatch` package (to prepend and append, respectively). (See [Enrico's helpful explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152811/7922).)

The below MWE is my attempt to solve this problem.

If I comment out the appending `\xapptocmd{\footnote}{\togglefalse{inFootnoteCommand}}{}{}` command, it works well (except for the obvious problem that it doesn't reset the boolean to false and, hence, thinks it's in the `\footnote` even after it's exited). See this output:

[image]

But when I leave the appending command uncommented, (a) it fails to reset the boolean and (b) the output falls apart both in the body text and in the footnote text, and (c) I get the error, associated with the `\footnote` commands itself:

> Missing \endcsname inserted.
>   
>   \unskip
>   I.38 \footnote
>   [Here's the footnote:\amIInAFootnote]
>   The control sequence marked  should not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

Here's the output:
[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{inFootnoteCommand}
\togglefalse{inFootnoteCommand}

\newcommand{\amIInAFootnote}{%
    \iftoggle{inFootnoteCommand}{%
        \textcolor{blue}{You are in a footnote.}
    }{%
        \textcolor{red}{You are NOT in a footnote.}
    }%
}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
This line intentionally left blank %To move the text closer to the footnote
\vspace{400pt}

\xpretocmd{\footnote}{\toggletrue{inFootnoteCommand}}{SUCCESS\\}{FAIL\\}
\xapptocmd{\footnote}{\togglefalse{inFootnoteCommand}}{SUCCESS\\}{FAIL\\}

Before a footnote: \amIInAFootnote.

At the end of this sentence is a footnote:%
    \footnote{Here’s the footnote: \amIInAFootnote}

Now, I'm back from the footnote: \amIInAFootnote
\end{document}
```

Comment: like most thinks a footnote is set in a local group so you have no need to reset at the end, everything will reset at that point anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `\footnote` definition, you'll find the following:

```
> \footnote=macro:
->\@ifnextchar [\@xfootnote {\stepcounter \@mpfn \protected@xdef \@thefnmark {\
thempfn }\@footnotemark \@footnotetext }.
```

This means that it never tries to process the fottnote text as its argument, but simply delegates this to `\@footnotetext`. When you patch `\footnote`, your `\togglefalse` becomes the `\@footnotetext` argument and messes things up. To fix it it's sufficient to apply your patches directly to `\@footnotetext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{inFootnoteCommand}
\togglefalse{inFootnoteCommand}

\newcommand{\amIInAFootnote}{%
    \iftoggle{inFootnoteCommand}{%
        \textcolor{blue}{You are in a footnote.}
    }{%
        \textcolor{red}{You are NOT in a footnote.}
    }%
}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
This line intentionally left blank %To move the text closer to the footnote
\vspace{400pt}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\@footnotetext}{\toggletrue{inFootnoteCommand}}{SUCCESS\\}{FAIL\\}
\xapptocmd{\@footnotetext}{\togglefalse{inFootnoteCommand}}{SUCCESS\\}{FAIL\\}
\makeatother

Before a footnote: \amIInAFootnote.

At the end of this sentence is a footnote:%
    \footnote{Here’s the footnote: \amIInAFootnote}

Now, I'm back from the footnote: \amIInAFootnote
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Given [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477982/7922) that "You do not need to reset at the end, simply set the toggle within the group," which does work in his answer, I thought I'd be able to comment out the `\xapptocmd` command that resets the boolean. But when I did so, it thinks you're in the footnote even after you left. That's puzzling.

Comment: This works perfectly. So does @DavidCarlisle's. I had to do a mental coin toss, slightly weighted in your favor because using the `xpatch` is a more-familiar syntax for me than the more-TeXish `\def` command syntax. So I'm awarding the question's answer to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you add

```
\show\footnote
```

after your patches you will find

```
> \footnote=\protected macro:
->\toggletrue {inFootnoteCommand}\@ifnextchar [\@xfootnote {\stepcounter \@mpfn
 \protected@xdef \@thefnmark {\thempfn }\@footnotemark \@footnotetext }\togglefalse {inFootnoteCommand}.
```

That is you are seting the toggle to true and false before the footnote argument is seen and breaking the look ahead for an optional argument as `\@ifnextchar` is always going to see `\togglefalse`

You do not need to reset at the end, simply set the toggle within the group, or in the common case that the only text set at footnotesize are footnotes you don't need a toggle at all, you can simply test the font size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{inFootnoteCommand}
\togglefalse{inFootnoteCommand}

\makeatletter
\let\saved@makefntext\@makefntext
\def\@makefntext#1{\saved@makefntext{\toggletrue{inFootnoteCommand}#1}}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
This line intentionally left blank %To move the text closer to the footnote
\vspace{400pt}

\newcommand{\amIInAFootnote}{%
    \iftoggle{inFootnoteCommand}{%
        \textcolor{blue}{You are in a footnote.}%%%
    }{%
        \textcolor{red}{You are NOT in a footnote.}%%%
    }%
}
Before a footnote: \amIInAFootnote.

At the end of this sentence is a footnote:%
    \footnote{Here’s the footnote: \amIInAFootnote}

Now, I'm back from the footnote: \amIInAFootnote
\end{document}
```

Comment: David, (A) I think the `xs` in `#1xs` (in the `\def` command) is a typo. (It shows up erroneously at the end of the footnote text.
(B) Since \footnotetext can also take an optional argument, I'm curious why this approach (of using `\let`) seems to work fine even when you use an optional argument on the original `\footnote`. (It does work, I checked.) I'm guessing that the optional argument to `\footnote` actually becomes the mandatory argument by the time it's passed to `\footnotetext`

Comment: @JimRatliff oops xs deleted. yes `\@makefntext` is the internal command used by `\footnote` and `\footnotetext` and is (unlike those two) defined in the class file to set up the class specific style for footnotes, whereas `\footnote` itself is defined in the latex format.

Comment: David, your method was working fine for me until I tried a multi-paragraph footnote. If you change `\footnote{Here’s the footnote: \amIInAFootnote}` to `\footnote{Here’s the footnote: \amIInAFootnote  \par Here's a second paragraph in same footnote.}` things fall apart: The footnote text omits everything before the `\par`, including the footnote number itself. There's also a Runaway Argument error regarding `{\rule \z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces`. [Sergei Golovan's answer using `xpatch`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477983/7922) does work successfully with multiple paragraphs.