# Checking environment in order to end it

Tags: environments, conditionals, verse

I used to typeset verse with `memoir` package using some heavy `\vspace` trickery. The verse environment was too hard to control in terms of vertical space due to the immense amount of obscure glue. For instance, whenever I inserted a centered line (header, remark etc.) within a verse, the spacing was almost uncontrollable. The whole document started with `\begin{verse}`, contained verse with headers and ended with `\end{verse}`

To avoid hundreds of manual environment invocations, a [prior answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-code-is-inside-a-certain-environment) was implemented in order to provide an environment detector (`\Bverse` to begin `verse` if not inside one already, `\Everse` to end one). I defined `\ACT`, `\SCENE`, `\descr` and `\hero` commands so as to check whether we are inside a verse environment, end if yes, typeset the ornate header and then resume the verse environment. However, the provided example fails to terminate the environments and goes on nesting them.

```
! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.
l.61 \herov{Альцест}
```

1. Why are my environments being nested?
2. Isn’t there a better solution to break a long verse with interwoven headers?

Please excuse the redundant working example, I did my best to minimize it in order to obtain the “too deeply nested” error. My example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\sodef\sohe{}{.19em}{.6em plus.05em}{.5em plus.05em minus.05em}
\newcommand{\hero}[1]{\sohe{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Bverse}{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\@verse
  \else
  \begin{verse}
  \fi}
\newcommand\@verse{verse}
\newcommand{\Everse}{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\@verse
  \end{verse}
  \else
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{center*}{\setlength\topsep{0pt}\setlength\parskip{0pt}\begin{center}}{\end{center}}

\newcommand{\SCENE}[1]{\Everse %
\begin{center*}\textsc{ #1}\end{center*}%
\Bverse %
}
\newcommand{\ACT}[1]{\Everse %
\newpage\begin{center*}\textsc{\textbf{\large #1}}\end{center*}%
\Bverse %
}
\newcommand{\descr}[1]{%
\Everse %
\begin{center*}\small #1\end{center*} %
\Bverse %
}
\newcommand{\herov}[1]{\Everse%
\begin{center*} \hero{#1} \end{center*}%
\Bverse%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}

\ACT{Действие первое}

\SCENE{Явление первое}

\descr{\hero{Альцест} и \hero{Филинт}.}

\herov{Альцест}
Как шутки эти здесь некстати "--- просто срам!

\herov{Филинт}
Ну, шутки в сторону. Чего же нужно вам?

\herov{Альцест}
Чтоб люди искренни всегда и честны были \\
И только правду бы, от сердца, говорили.

\herov{Филинт}
Когда мы чьим-нибудь приветом польщены, \\
Платить мы тою же монетою должны: \\
Приветом за привет, услугой за услугу, \\
За клятву "--- клятвою, как преданному другу.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** Please see the picture of the version I had had before “optimizing” the code.
[image: Verse typeset with custom headers in between]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure if the output is what you need; but if I redefine `\Bverse` and `\Everse` to do nothing and `\newenvironment{center*}{\par\centering}{\par}`, I get the document compiled.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the request of the desired output, please see the enclosed picture. The idea is: the blunt way to typeset it is to enclose each and every set of lines in its own `verse` environment, but what I want is to begin a `verse` environment and terminate it with custom designed centered lines, and start a new `verse` afterwards, since it is very hard to fine-tune penalties, glue and breaking rules between those different types of centered announcements inside `verse` environment.