# @currenvir check returns false

Tags: environments, conditionals, exam

Good day,

I'm trying to check for the `solution` environment and close it if it's open.
I have tried [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-code-is-inside-a-certain-environment) and checking directly for the `@insolution` toggle that is set by `solution` environment when exam document class is used, but both return false.

I'm pretty sure that I'm making some very stupid mistake, but can not find it.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\printanswerstrue

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question
\emph{TEST QUESTION}

\end{questions}
\begin{solution}

% Use @currenvir to check if we are in the solution environment
\ifx\@currenvir\@solution
currenvir is solution
\else
currenvir is not solution
\fi

% Use @insolutiontrue to check if we are in the solution environment
\if@insolution
in solution is TRUE
\else
in solution is FALSE
\fi
\emph{TEST SOLUTION}

\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

And here is what it produces:

[image: MWE]

As one can see, both checks return FALSE, while they should instead return TRUE.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to say `\makeatletter` before trying to use commands with `@` in their name (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/134574).

Comment: ...and then `\makeatother` when you're finished making changes (ideally)!

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. Now I have to also remove some `\makeatletter` as I copied them with some of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands with the `@` character can only be called between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (see the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) for a more detailed explanation on that).

The correct way to achieve what you are trying to do here would be to define new commands in the preamble, between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Also, the command `\@solution` is in fact not defined, so you have to define it. Here is a complete example.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\printanswerstrue
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@solution}{TheSolution}
\newcommand{\ifcurrenvirsolution}{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\@solution
        currenvir is solution
    \else
        currenvir is not solution
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\ifinsolution}{%
    \if@insolution
        in solution is TRUE
    \else
        in solution is FALSE
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question
\emph{TEST QUESTION}

\end{questions}
\begin{solution}

\ifcurrenvirsolution

\ifinsolution

\emph{TEST SOLUTION}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` can be used (almost) anywhere. The _recommendation_, however, is that all commands are defined in the preamble, and thus `\makeatletter` should not be necessary in the document

Comment: Thanks! I was not so sure about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works perfectly.